# Determine singular point of $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{\sin\frac{1}{z}}$ at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

> Determine singular point of $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{\sin\frac{1}{z}}$  at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$

I believe $z=0$ is an essential singular point because I cannot find the limit of this function and $z=\infty$ is removable singular point.

Am I right?

Comment: There are also simple pole singularities at $z=1/(n\pi)$ for all $n\ne 0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV So I'm right when z=0 and z=infinity?

Comment: $z=\infty$ will not be a removable singularity.  Think about $z=\frac{1}{\zeta}$ as $\zeta$ goes to $0$ in the exponential.

Comment: @sharding4 so what point it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $e^z$ is non singular at $z=0$ and $e^0=1$, you can just look at
$$
\frac{1}{\sin(1/z)}
$$
and this has no limit for $z\to0$: approach $0$ with $\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$ or $-\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$.

The given function has no limit for $z\to\infty$ either. Consider instead
$$
g(w)=\frac{e^{1/w}}{\sin w}
$$
and its behavior at $0$. In order for $0$ to be a removable singularity you need $\lim\limits_{w\to0}e^{1/w}=0$, which doesn't hold. Can $w=0$ be a pole?